# «Что скажите» или «что скажете»?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, глаголы

Часто писал что–то вроде:

> У меня есть вот такая замечательная идея! Что скажите?

Но меня поправили, указав на то, что верно писать «что скаж**е**те». Пожалуйста, подскажите, какое правило используется, почему правильно писать через «е»?

Comment: Ещё и дефис нужно вместо короткого тире.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В вашем случае однозначно: `Что скажете?`

> ска́жете — скажи́те

Варианты:

> Скажи́те, как Вам моя идея?

---

Слово «скажете» с окончанием `-ете` — это [изъявительное наклонение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) глагола сказать:

> вы (**что сделаете?**) ска́жете.

---

Слово `скажите` с суффиксом `-и` — это [повелительное наклонение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), выражающее просьбу или приказ:

> вы (**что сделайте?**) скажи́те.

Comment: Так у вас ите/ете - окончание или суффикс?!

Comment: `-и` суффикс, `-те, -ете` - окончания

Comment: *-и суффикс, -те, -ете - окончания* - можно узнать, где такому учат?!

Comment: В интернете, вестимо. [скажете](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=скажете), [скажите](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=скажите). Можно узнать, а как правильно?!

Comment: Единого мнения тут пока не выработано. Меня заинтересовало не то, что "ете" трактуется как окончание, а то, что проповедуется разный подход к "ете" и "ите". Я-то полагаю, что "ите" и "ете" - глагольные суффиксы, оба составные. С этим можно спорить, но тогда уж быть последовательным, и не противопоставлять "ете" и "ите".

Answer (score 8):

Определяем спряжение глагола, он у нас I спряжения: сказ**ать**.
Во 2-м лице множественного числа пишут окончание *-ете*.

То есть правильный вариант:

> Что скаж**е**те?

[Ссылка по теме](https://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=sprjazenie_glagolov_5)

Answer (score 4):

В форме будущего или настоящего времени - под ударением корневая гласная, затем пишется безударное Е:

> Что скáжете на этот счёт?
>
> Вы часто тут п**и**шете?
>
> Сегодня Вы вновь п**и**лите эти злосчастные гири?

В форме повелительного наклонения - безударная корневая гласная, затем пишется ударное И:

> Скаж**и**те, как Вам такой вариант?
>
> Пиш**и**те, Шура, пиш**и**те.
>
> Пил**и**те, Шура, пил**и**те.

Comment: Исходя из пояснения, может показаться, что третье предложение в первом блоке содержит ошибку. =) Опять же, только первое предложение в будущем времени..

Comment: Здесь нет корневых гласных. Корень пис/пиш, Единственная корневая - И между П и С/Ш. А то, что вы  выделили - глагольные суффиксы.

Comment: @behemothus Посмотрите внимательнее, пожалуйста. В первом блоке выделены корневые гласные под ударением, а во втором не корневые, но тоже под ударением (а про корневые сказано, что они безударные). Так всё и подразумевалось.

Answer (score 2):

Николай, ответ вам дали исчерпывающий, глагол первого спряжения, поэтому в изъявительном наклонении Е: что скажете.
Но вообще я бы посоветовал, чтобы не лезть каждый раз в академические дебри и разборки на тему окончание тут или суффикс (второе вернее, хотя учебники трактуют по-разному), просто выучить без всяких правил два критически важных слова: *"(Это вы завтра) ск**а**жете, нап**и**шете"* и *"напиш**и**те, скаж**и**те (это сегодня)"*.

В обоих случаях ошибка массовая, не знаю уж почему... Но проще, повторюсь, выучить, чем каждый раз обращаться к правилам.